# C# Listview items in wrong row

Tags: c#, winforms

It seems like items are appearing in the wrong row when i add on the second column. Any reason why?

```
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(i.ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.SubItems.Add(i.ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

[Image how it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBm8J.png)

Comment: And what do you expect to be the result of this code?

Comment: I dont know if you see on the image. But it should appear right after the second column instead it appears in the second column but it seems like it continues from the row it stopped from the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basile Perrenoud's answer is right but you asked then what if you need to do the same but from 2 different loops so here is the solution

```
List<ListViewItem> items = new List<ListViewItems>();

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(i.ToString());
    items.Add(item);
}

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    items[i-1].SubItems.Add(i.ToString());
}

foreach(ListViewItem item in items)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

So what we have done is created ListViewItems from first loop and temporary added them to `List<>()`, Then with second loop we assigned `SubItem` for each of our `ListViewItem` inside list and finally we loop through each item in our list and add new item to our `listView` with it.

So at the start we have data in List like this:

```
|itemValue    |subItem     |
|null         |null        |
```

After first loop our List looked like this:

```
|itemValue    |subItem     |
|1            |null        |
|2            |null        |
|3            |null        |
|4            |null        |
|5            |null        |
|6            |null        |
|7            |null        |
|8            |null        |
|9            |null        |
|10           |null        |
```

And after second loop we have it like this:

```
|itemValue    |subItem  |
|1            |1        |
|2            |2        |
|3            |3        |
|4            |4        |
|5            |5        |
|6            |6        |
|7            |7        |
|8            |8        | 
|9            |9        |
|10           |10       |
```

With last loop we get each item from List and use it to create new Item inside `listView`

Comment: Thanks, this is what i exactly looked for!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that `SubItems` are the columns. However, each ListViewItem you add will represent a line. In your code, you add 20 items. This is why you have 20 lines.

Try adding the second column on the same item:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(i.ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(i.ToString());
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Or alternatively

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    string[] elements = new string[2];
    elements[0] = i.ToString();
    elements[1] = i.ToString();
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(elements);
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to fill the texts from two different loops:

```
column0 = new string[10];
for(int = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    // Fill all elements of the first column
}

column1 = new string[10];
for(int = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    // Fill all elements of the secondcolumn
}

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    string[] elements = new string[2];
    elements[0] = column0[i];
    elements[1] = column0[1];
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(elements);
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Or you can use the solution proposed by @Aleksa Ristic

Comment: The example i gave is the same loop. But if i have two different loops with different values. Such as one who is 1-10 and another is 5 different strings. How will i fix it? Since i will get same outcome as my first approach.

Comment: Why do you mean by 2 different loops and 5 different strings

Comment: I mean if i have two loops. One which give numbers and another loop that looping array with different names. So i cant have it in a one loop and need two loops then. But then i will be back at square one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i saw this after. And works also